# Why is beautifoulsount find_all missing this element when searching if text contains a string?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have this test HTML page

```
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="created" content="2020-05-29T11:12:00.0000000" />
     </head>
     <body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
      <div id="div:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{216}" style="position:absolute;left:72px;top:43px;width:696px">
       <p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{218}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="font-weight:bold">Test1###yrdy</span></p>
       <p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{220}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test2###qweqwe</p>
       <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{22}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="color:red">Test3</span> ###qweqeqwe</p>
       <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{17}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test4 ### sfsfsdfds</p>
       <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{19}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test5### 121212</p>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

After turning the above into a soup I am doing this

```
 for element in soup.find_all(["p"],text=re.compile("###")):
     print(element)
```

The above prints these

```
    <p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{218}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="font-weight:bold">Test1###yrdy</span></p>
    <p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{220}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test2###qweqwe</p>
    <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{17}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test4 ### sfsfsdfds</p>
    <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{19}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test5### 121212</p>
```

Why is it skipping the Test3 corresponding p?

Update:
Andrej, your suggestion works but it puzzles me because searching for
 soup.find_all(["p"],text=re.compile("###")) should have the same effect. This

```
 for p in soup.html.body.find_all("p"):
    print(p.text)
```

Test1###yrdy
Test2###qweqwe
Test3 ###qweqeqwe
Test4 ### sfsfsdfds
Test5### 121212

Comment: `###` is missing. why are you using `regex`?

Comment: scroll to the right , there is a ### in <span style="color:red">Test3</span> ###qweqeqwe  Yes see the python code (re.compile ('###'))

Comment: Yes but not within span tag

Comment: not within a span but within a p tag
my understanding is that .text for that p tag would be Test3###qweqeqwe   am I wrong?

Comment: @MiniMe It's limitation of `BeautifulSoup`, in this case it's inconsistent (I think). To have more robust results, you can use something with lambda, for example `soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='p' and '###' in tag.text)`

Comment: see the update please

Comment: @MiniMe Yes, it should have the effect you described. But it doesn't - maybe it's bug, or how the internals of bs4 are implemented? Maybe someone more experienced could tell why it is like it is. Myself, I don't use regular expressions in parameters very much (you can use it inside the lambda however!)

Comment: OK I will leave the question without answer maybe someone who knows more about BS can answer this, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

*Test3 does not have **`###`** with in **`span, P`** tag, to fix that use `soup.select('p')`*

*Or simply use `for element in soup.find_all(['p']):` for all p tag*

---

*Example*

---

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <meta name="created" content="2020-05-29T11:12:00.0000000" />
        </head>
        <body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
            <div id="div:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{216}" style="position:absolute;left:72px;top:43px;width:696px">
                <p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{218}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="font-weight:bold">Test1###yrdy</span></p>
                <p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{220}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test2###qweqwe</p>
                <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{22}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="color:red">Test3 </span> ###qweqeqwe</p>
                <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{17}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test4 ### sfsfsdfds</p>
                <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{19}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test5### 121212</p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
for element in soup.select('p'):
    print(element)
```

---

*Prints out all*

---

```
<p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{218}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="font-weight:bold">Test1###yrdy</span></p>
<p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{220}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test2###qweqwe</p>
<p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{22}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="color:red">Test3 </span> ###qweqeqwe</p>
<p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{17}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test4 ### sfsfsdfds</p>
<p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{19}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test5### 121212</p>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `soup.select()` doesn't have `text=` parameter, so it ignores it and prints all `<p>` tags